# Flask-sqlalchemy losing connection after restarting of DB server

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I use flask-sqlalchemy in my application. DB is postgresql 9.3.
I have simple init of db, model and view:

```
from config import *
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, HOST, DB_NAME)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

@app.route('/users/')
def users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return '1'
```

And all works fine. But when happens DB server restarting (`sudo service postgresql restart`), on first request to the `/users/` I obtain `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError`:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) terminating connection due to administrator command
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
 [SQL: ....
```

Is there any way to renew connection inside view, or setup flask-sqlalchemy in another way for renew connection automatically?

UPDATE.

I ended up with using clear SQLAlchemy, declaring engine, metadata and db_session for every view, where I critically need it.

It is not solution of question, just a 'hack'.

So question is open. I am sure, It will be nice to find solution for this :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#dealing-with-disconnects) explains that the default behaviour is to handle disconnects optimistically. Did you try another request - the connection should have re-established itself ? I've just tested this with a Flask/Postgres/Windows project and it works.

*In a typical web application using an ORM Session, the above condition would correspond to a single request failing with a 500 error, then the web application continuing normally beyond that. Hence the approach is “optimistic” in that frequent database restarts are not anticipated.*

If you want the connection state to be checked prior to a connection attempt you need to write code that handles disconnects pessimistically. The following example code is provided at the documentation:

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.pool import Pool

@event.listens_for(Pool, "checkout")
def ping_connection(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT 1")
    except:
        # optional - dispose the whole pool
        # instead of invalidating one at a time
        # connection_proxy._pool.dispose()

        # raise DisconnectionError - pool will try
        # connecting again up to three times before raising.
        raise exc.DisconnectionError()
    cursor.close()
```

Here's some screenshots of the event being caught in PyCharm's debugger:

**Windows 7 (Postgres 9.4, Flask 0.10.1, SQLAlchemy 1.0.11, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 and psycopg 2.6.1)**

*On first db request*
[image]
*After db restart*
[image]

**Ubuntu 14.04 (Postgres 9.4, Flask 0.10.1, SQLAlchemy 1.0.8, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.0 and psycopg 2.5.5)**

*On first db request*
[image]
*After db restart*[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't help. First request after restart of DB server this event dont execute. And if call ping_connection(params) function inside view, it doesn't help.

Comment: @user1931780 - interesting - I ran the code through PyCharm's debugger (both on Windows and Ubuntu) and the restart was handled as expected.I've listed the library versions that were used.

Comment: Great post! Works as expected! Thanks a lot @pjcunningham!

Answer (score 5):

In plain `SQLAlchemy` you can add the [`pool_pre_ping=True` kwarg](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) when calling the `create_engine` function to fix this issue.

When using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` you can use the same argument, but you need to pass it as a dict in the [`engine_options` kwarg](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy):

```
app.db = SQLAlchemy(app, engine_options={"pool_pre_ping": True})
```